# How to detect when two objects touch each other?

Tags: ios, lua, sdk, coronasdk

What is the code to detect when two objects (new rect) touch each other?

I am new to lua so the full code will be appreciated

Here is code

```
rect20 = display.newRect( 100, 100, 1298.5, 50 )
```

Comment: You have to subscribe to their movement event and check their position to see if they have any overlap.

Comment: @Akbari what is the code for this thanks

Comment: pls refer :- http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You can read https://docs.coronalabs.com/daily/guide/physics/collisionDetection/index.html guide on Corona Labs docs, also you have code examples to try and learn.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to know two objects' collision information, just follow [Local Collision Handling](https://docs.coronalabs.com/daily/guide/physics/collisionDetection/index.html#TOC)
title from Corona's Documentation Page(as Koormo mentioned before). If you want to research about physics, there is a good guide in Corona's Documentation Page, you can read the guide from [Physics](https://docs.coronalabs.com/daily/guide/index.html#physics)
link. There are a few examples that you may need when you make this kind of stuff.